# Creating cache for:

Tags: c++, cache, kate

I just started using kate to program in c++ but whenever I save a file it creates a cache, for example

Creating the cache for:  "/home/users/Documents/file.cc"

how can I stop it? It didnt do it before

Comment: Same problem here on Kubuntu 16.10. Did you find any solution?